# Best way to join two adjacent array elements at each nth index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assuming the following array example:

```
const arr = ['mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'melon', 'orange', 'banana']
```

how do I convert it to look like this:

```
const result = ['mango apple', 'kiwi', 'melon orange', 'banana']
```

I've tried with a foor loop, but I'm unsure of the algorithm in the if condition or if it's even the best way, or perhaps reduce is better?

```js
const arr = ['mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'melon', 'orange', 'banana']

let n = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
     //Something like simply: i % 2 == 0
      //Is obviously not good enough
      if (/* What here?*/) {
      n.push(arr[i] + ' ' + arr[i+1])
     } else {
      n.push(arr[i])
     }
    }
```

Comment: Whats is the condition based on which you have to convert the array?

Comment: What logic prevents `kiwi melon`

Comment: @Tuna Every first two out of three elements should be join and so on, so: 1 2, 3, 4 5, 6

Comment: You usually use modulus (`%`) for this kind of thing, something like `if ((i % 2) == 0) {..}`

Comment: @keith thats the problem I need some logic to prevent that and join only mango apple and so on

Comment: @Titus I know that's what I've tried but taking only the even ones doesn't help I need some other rule

Comment: It can work, you just need to use `i % 3 == 0` and increment `i` when you use two elements of `arr`.

Comment: @Titus I've tried it, but it was very late last night :) I'll try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is like this:

```js
const arr = ['mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'melon', 'orange',
  'banana', 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6]
let n = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=3 ) {
  n.push(arr[i] + ' ' + arr[i+1]);
   n.push(arr[i+2]);
}
console.log(n);
// output
// ["mango apple", "kiwi", "melon orange", "banana", "1 2", 3, "4 5", 6]
```

**EDIT:** As per Shiva's comment, I have modified code to handle out of index values

```
const arr = ['mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'melon']
let n = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=3 ) {
    if(arr[i] === undefined) {
        break;
    }

    let first = arr[i];
    if(arr[i+1] !== undefined) {
        first+= ' ' + arr[i+1];
    }
    n.push(first);
    if(arr[i+2] !== undefined) {
        n.push(arr[i+2]);
    }
}
console.log(n);
// output
// ["mango apple", "kiwi", "melon"]
```

Comment: this gets it done but what if arr=['mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'melon'], your code will return ["mango apple", "kiwi, ""melon undefiend", "undefined"]? right?

Comment: @ShivaBurade Nice catch. I have updated the code to handle such cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use modulus (`%`) for this, here is an example:

```js
var arr = ['mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'melon', 'orange', 'banana'];
var result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0 && i + 1 < arr.length) {
    result.push(`${arr[i]} ${arr[i + 1]}`);
    i++;
  } else {
    result.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an `offset` for getting the real index `i + offset` and iterate a virtual index `i` for getting the check done.

```js
var array = ['mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'melon', 'orange', 'banana'],
    n = 2,
    offset = 0,
    result = [];

for (let i = 0; i + offset < array.length; i++) {
    result.push(i % n == 0
        ? array[i + offset] + ' ' + array[i + 1 + offset++]
        : array[i + offset]
    );
}

console.log(result);
```

An approach with a generator function.

```js
function* getNTh(array, n) {
    var i = 0, offset = 0;

    while (i + offset < array.length) {
        yield i % n == 0
            ? array[i + offset] + ' ' + array[i + 1 + offset++]
            : array[i + offset];
        i++;
    }
}

console.log([...getNTh(['mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'melon', 'orange', 'banana'], 2)]);
console.log([...getNTh(['mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'melon', 'orange', 'banana'], 3)]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of re-using code.  IOW: I'm a lazy programmer. :)

As such from what I can gather the OP is really after a pattern iterator.  Because something like this might be useful for the future this is something I'd try and generalise and make into a function.

With this in mind, I'm a big fan of the new Javascript feature called Iterators and generators. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators  and this problems seems to fit nicely here for something that could get re-used again & again.

ps. Even if you want to target browsers that don't have generators yet, save yourself a life of misery and get your Javscript transpiled.  Most modern browsers already have good support too -> https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-generators

Below is an example, and you can see how easy it is then to change the pattern, without having to worry about modulus & stepping etc.

```js
function *patternIter(pattern, len) {
  let p = 0, ps = pattern[p], c;
  for (l = 0; l < len; l += 1) {
    if (!c) c = {offset: l, size: 0};
    c.size += 1;
    if (c.size === ps) {
      yield c;
      c = undefined;
      p += 1; ps = pattern[p % pattern.length];
    }
  }
  if (c) yield c;
}

const arr = ['mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'melon', 'orange', 'banana']

function showPattern(p) {
  console.log('Pattern ' + p.join(", "));
  console.log(
    [...patternIter(p, arr.length)]
    .map(m => arr.slice(m.offset, m.offset + m.size)
    .join(" ")).join(",  ")
  );
}

showPattern([1, 2]);
showPattern([3, 2, 1]);
showPattern([1, 3, 2]);
showPattern([3, 1]);
```